# Pass Django Data into Vue component

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Django as a backend and I am trying to pass some data into a Vue table component that I made. I set it up using this [tutorial](https://github.com/michaelbukachi/django-vuejs-tutorial/wiki/Django-Vue.js-Integration-Tutorial) The component is showing up fine while using a webpack. I am trying to set the data to a javascript constant and then pass it into the component. The data does not appear to be passing through. Here is how my scripts are laid out.

**index.html**

```
{% block content %}
<script>
  const gridData = {{json_data|safe}};
  console.log(gridData)
</script>

    <div id="app">
        <table_component
        v-bind:tableData=this.gridData
        >
        </table_component>

    </div>  
{% end block %}
```

**myComponent.vue script seciton**

```
export default {
  name: 'table_component',
    props: {
    tableData: Array
  },
  data() {
      return {

      }
  },
  components: {
    Grid,
    ButtonModal
  },
  created(){
    console.log(this.tableData)
  },
}
```

When I look at the console, it is not showing any data. It just says undefined.

**view.py**

```
class CurrentClassroomView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        db_data = list(myData.objects.all().values())
        my_json_data = json.dumps(db_data)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'json_data':my_json_data})
```

I am getting this in the console that I am not sure what that means and why it is making everything lowercase even though I'm passing it with upper case letters.

```
[Vue tip]: Prop "griddata" is passed to component <Anonymous>, but the declared prop name is "gridData". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and camelCased props need to use their kebab-case equivalents when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "grid-data" instead of "GridData".
tip @ vue.js:639
extractPropsFromVNodeData @ vue.js:2294
createComponent @ vue.js:3233
_createElement @ vue.js:3427
createElement @ vue.js:3359
vm._c @ vue.js:3496
eval @ VM1553:3
Vue._render @ vue.js:3550
updateComponent @ vue.js:4066
get @ vue.js:4477
Watcher @ vue.js:4466
mountComponent @ vue.js:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.js:9043
Vue.$mount @ vue.js:11943
Vue._init @ vue.js:5011
Vue @ vue.js:5077
eval @ index.js:14
./assets/js/index.js @ app.js:409
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:84
(anonymous) @ app.js:87
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: I'm also using Django as backend and vuejs as frontend. My advice is the following : use an API and query it from vuejs. You can use graphene-django (the graphql implementation for django) to build an API alongside with apollo to query the graphql endpoint (that's what I'm actually doing) or DRF (Django Rest Framework).
Otherwise I don't know how to directly pass data from django to vuejs.

Answer (score 10):

When you set `gridData` and try to bind it to a Vue component it is not working because they have different contexts. When you dealing with Vue components you can only access data defined inside the Vue instance. Additionally, `{{json_data|safe}}` is vulnerable to XSS-type attacks.

However, it is very easy to safely pass data from Django to a Vue component, we just have to use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter and load the data in Vue's `mounted` hook.

In **views.py** just pass the list to the template, no need to use `json.dumps()`:

```
class CurrentClassroomView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'home/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        db_data = list(myData.objects.all().values())
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'json_data':db_data})
```

In **index.html**, we will use the `json_script` template tag to create a JSON formatted representation of `json_data` variable:

```
{% block content %}
{{ json_data|json_script:"json_data" }}

<div id="app">
    <table_component></table_component>
</div>  
{% end block %}
```

This will create a `<script>` block, e.g.:

```
<script id="json_data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world"}</script>
```

And finally, in **myComponent.vue**, we load, JSON-decode and set the data in the [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook:

```
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          tableData
      }
  },
  components: {
    Grid,
    ButtonModal
  },
  mounted() {
    this.tableData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json_data').textContent)
  },
}
```

Comment: using `document.getElementById()` can slow down the app as it reads and scans the entire HTML and there is no inherent dependency or relationship between the script tag and the component.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just pass Django's server-side props straight into a child component that uses it. Mine's set up like this:

```
{% extends "ExpenseTracker/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div id="transactionlabeling_view"
>
 <transactions-table 
 :cached_items = "{{transactions}}"
 :account_types = "{{account_types}}"
 ></transactions-table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

where there's a Vue component that is mounted on "#transactionlabeling_view". There, I imported the child component `transactions-table` where I passed on the server side props from Django view ({{transactions}} & {{account_types}}) into props inside `transactions-table` component (:cached_items & :account_types):

```
props:{
    cached_items:null,
    account_types:null
},
```

It's convenient that you don't have to JSON.parse those two props, vue got that job done for you. But you do need to use JSON.dump on {{transactions}} & {{account_types}} before passing it as context in the html. works like a charm, I use vue 3.2.6 and Django 4.1.6 and have vue installed inside django.